# c3p0 inactive connection not being culled from connection pool after max wait time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have an existing app that utilizes Spring 3.0.3, Hibernate 3.6.0 and an Oracle DB.

I've got it set up and running c3p0 but I noticed something strange that I can't really figure out.

This is my Spring set up

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClass" value="${xxgglom.driver}" />
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}" />
<property name="user" value="${username}" />
<property name="password" value="${password}" />
<property name="minPoolSize" value='5' />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="240" />
<property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="180" />
<property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" />
<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
```

I check the database v$session and I see it creates the 5 connections in the pool. I'll start using the app and it will increase the pool size when needed. So I can tell C3P0 is working from checking the logs. The one issue I'm having is. There are these inactive connections, that are pass the maxIdleTime.

I check their alive times and they're way pass the 240 seconds. I check the database again and they all show inactive but when I look in the logs tell me this.

```
trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@282fafdd [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@5f9f7637)
```

I'm not sure what's going on exactly but after awhile these idle connections start piling up, and they don't seem to be getting culled from the connection pool. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: just curious how are you checking the c3p0 connections info?
I saw some references to JMX or JConsole connecting to remote boxes to get c3p0 info by opening them up via java env args. Is that how you are checking pooling info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxIdleTime` doesn't guarantee that Connections will be culled at any particular time. As long as each Connection is used at least once every 4 minutes under your config, they won't be culled. If you want to put an unconditional limit on Connections' live-time (I don't know why you would), you can use `maxConnectionAge`.

Comment: The connection I'm looking at never gets used within the maxIdleTime. It just sits there. Currently it's second_in_wait is 3614 seconds. Nobody is using the app except me. There's currently another connection that has the same issue and it's sitting at 1325 seconds of being idle. The issue is they're not being reused at all.

Comment: What do you mean "not being reused". Are you seeing the managed count go up and up, or on the server side are you seeing more open Connections than the number logged as managed?

Comment: It keeps going up. Example, I have 2 of these idle connections that are not being culled. After awhile and some use. It starts to become 3, then 4, then 5 and the pool will just start getting larger because it thinks those 5 connections are being used when they're really not.

Comment: so does the unused count fall? is it like `[managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0]` then `[managed: 5, unused: 3, excluded: 0]` then `[managed: 5, unused: 2, excluded: 0]`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: OK. So that's not a `maxIdleTime` issue. It's a Connection leak. Each time you use the application, the Connection is getting checked out, but it isn't being returned to the pool. How does your application work with the Connections?

Comment: It basically just opens a connection to the DB using hibernate and makes a query. After the it's done. It closes the connection. I do see connections that are queried are returned back to the pool. I just noticed one thing, everytime I open the app, it creates an one of the connections that leaks. I just don't know where to close it exactly.

Comment: It's got to be sure to close the Connection (or the Hibernate Session that wraps a Connection). If possible, it should work with the Connection entirely in a [try-with-resources block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), opening or acquiring the Connection in the parenthesized initialization statement to ensure that it will be close()ed.

Comment: Ahh, I found a class where it was opening up sessions. I saw it earlier but I saw that it was closing connections but it wasn't closing the sessions. I closed the session and I no longer see these strange idle connections in the pool anymore! Thank you!